# I want to display the reversed word in line only, but it displays the reversed of all line as well

Tags: java

My code was about to display the reversed order of the user input. But it doesn't display. It display nothing.

I want the output to be like this

input
1.hello world
2.welcome to programming

Intended Output

1. world hello
2. programming to welcome

But it displays
1.programming to welcome
2.world hello

Here's the code

```
public static void main (String   args[])
{  
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int test_no;
 String cases = " "; 

   test_no = sc.nextInt();
   sc.nextLine();
   
   String [] list = new String[test_no];
         
     for(int i = 0 ; i < test_no; i++ )
     {
       list[i] = sc.nextLine();
     
     for(int j = list.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
     {
       String [] ar = list[i].split(" ");
     
       for(int k = ar.length -1; k >= 0; k--)
       {
         System.out.println(ar[k]+" ");
       }
       System.out.println();
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in both of your inner for loops. The loop conditions are never met, so the code inside the loop is not executed.

The condition in your second for loop `j <= 0` should be `j >= 0`. Same for the third loop with `k <= 0`, which should be `k >= 0`.

I restructured your code, so that all of the input is taken first and then the expected output is produced:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int testNo = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    String[] list = new String[test_no];

    // first take all of the user input
    for (int i = 0; i < testNo; i++) {
        list[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    // then loop the array of input
    for (int j = 0; j < testNo; j++) {
        // split each line
        String[] ar = list[j].split(" ");
        // and print in reverse
        for (int k = ar.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            System.out.println(ar[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Input:

```
2
hello world
welcome to programming
```

Output:

```
world
hello

programming
to
welcome
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I fix the order, I just want to print the reversed word in a line, not the line itself. For example. In my input I have 2 input, like Hello Word and Welcome to programming, in my code it displays the programming to welcome first rather than word hello

Comment: @MAnChuMan can you edit your question, and add your current input, output and expected output? Or best would be to ask a new question, because this question is about why your print-statements are not executing.

Comment: Hello , I cant further ask any question, because I was restricted, but I managed to get the answer, thank you

Comment: @MAnChuMan I added an update.